# Run a long-running command and do a background check in the meanwhile - in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I need to run a long-running command and interrupt it if some background check fails.
More specifically: tail aws logs while the task is running - and stop after the task finished.

My current approach is:

```
while(checkRunning(task)) {
    sh("timeout 10 ${command} || true")
}
```

where:

command:
    `awslogs get ...`

checkRunning:
    `aws ecs describe-tasks ... -query 'tasks[0].lastStatus'`

But this creates small fragments from the whole output.

Is there a better way to do this?
e.g. parallel steps and interrupting one from the other

UPDATE: Now I see two possibilities:
1. implement in bash or other shell
2. create a custom wrapper (e.g. checking this: https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-aws-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/de/taimos/pipeline/aws/WithAWSStep.java)

Answer (score 0):

I also tried with implementing a groovy lib to do the job:

```
* Usage:
* <pre><code>
* doUntil task: {
*     sh 'awslogs get ...'
* }, until: {
*     runMyCheck()
* }
*
* @params params [task: {}, until: {}]
*/

def call (params) {
    parallel ( "main": {(params.task)()},
        "background": {
            timeout(60) {
                waitUntil {
                    sleep 10
                    if( (params.until)() )  error "Stopping background check"
                }
            }
        },
        failFast: true
    )
}
```

...which should work but behaves weirdly